# How to implement a lazy loading on Ion-card

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

So im using ionic with the firebase data and i have to load a lot of it.
And because of this massive data to load, not all images appear (As you can see on the screen shot).
So... what should i do and is it possible to lazy load the cards with the data.

[image]

there is my code

```
   <div *ngIf="postcall1">
      <ion-card (swipeleft)="goTochat(postscall1)" *ngFor="let postscall1 of postcall1">

        <img class="pP" src="https://ucarecdn.com/{{ postscall1.profilePic }}/-/scale_crop/200x200/center/" />

        <ion-img (press)="openOptionSheet(postcall1)" (click)="open(postscall1)"
          src="https://ucarecdn.com/{{postscall1.postboost1ID}}/-/preview/{{postscall1.effect}}"></ion-img>

       
        <ion-button mode="ios" class="this-button" color="light" fill="clear">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" [name]="heartType"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>

      </ion-card>
    </div>
```

and i have these 3 firebase function to load

```
 ngOnInit() {


    const postcall = this.aff.httpsCallable('postscall')
    this.sub = postcall({}).subscribe(data => {
      this.postcall = data

      console.log("postcall");
      console.log(this.postcall);
    })
    ///


    const postcall1 = this.aff.httpsCallable('postscall1')
    this.sub = postcall1({}).subscribe(data => {
      this.postcall1 = data

      console.log("postcall1");
      console.log(this.postcall1);
    })




  }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Ionic, put your items in an [Ion virtual scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll).

In the documentation, it is clearly explained that only the necessary elements will be loaded.

```
For performance reasons, not every record in the list is rendered at once; instead a small subset of records (enough to fill the viewport) are rendered and reused as the user scrolls.
```

Not tested code below, but this example might help you.

```html
<ion-virtual-scroll [items]="postcall1">
    <ion-card *virtualItem="let postscall1">
        <img class="pP" src="https://ucarecdn.com/{{ postscall1.profilePic }}/-/scale_crop/200x200/center/" />

        <ion-img (press)="openOptionSheet(postcall1)" (click)="open(postscall1)"
            src="https://ucarecdn.com/{{postscall1.postboost1ID}}/-/preview/{{postscall1.effect}}"></ion-img>

        
        <ion-button mode="ios" class="this-button" color="light" fill="clear">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" [name]="heartType"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
    </ion-card>
</ion-virtual-scroll>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i tried it and it works , but all my card are buged look at the picture on my question

Comment: @123 Not sure where is the problem, you should try setting the `approxItemHeight` variable in `ion-virtual-scroll`. [More info](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll#approximate-widths-and-heights)

Comment: do you have any other option ?